# Use a second Hard Drive to extend the / space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, gparted

I'm still a little new to Linux, and I need help with partitions

Some time ago, I had separated only `30GB` as partition for the system root directory `/` on my first HD, however now I am out of space and therefore I need more GB in my system root. I now bought a new HD with 1TB, I separated `500GB` for Linux, however I need to use these `500GB` to extend the space in `/`.

**Does anyone know how I can take the space allocated on my system root (30GB), and extend it with a space created on another Hard Drive (500GB)?** without it i can't download files on my Linux computer due to lack of space

Comment: Move your /home to the 500 GB space? I have a whole desktop system with virtualization and two VMs in under 30GB...but almost nothing in /home. 30GB is a LOT of space, if used wisely.

Comment: @user535733 how can I move the entire root directory to a new hard drive?

Comment: Lots of ways: Reinstall, cp, rsync, dd. Advantages and disadvantages to each. If you are new, a clean-install can be the easiest and safest way.

Comment: This is a great tutorial on moving your /home.  Do that, and 30G is plenty big for / in most cases.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving  It also makes it easier and safer to do a clean install when you upgrade to a new version.

Comment: @user535733 the problem is that I have two partitions, a 90GB partition that is the `/home` partition, and the 30GB partition that is the `/` partition, that is, everything that is within the 90GB is also within the 30GB , and I don't know if I can delete the 90GB partition without deleting the / home folder to extend with the 30GB partition. I also can't reinstall because I have some important content, otherwise I would have reinstalled some time ago

Comment: @OrganicMarble thank you very much, I'll take a look

Comment: Your backups should be so you can always reinstall whether Windows or LInux. What happens when your hard drive fails, you drop laptop, it gets stolen, and many other bad things. If you have good backups your data is safe, if not your data must not be important. Post your partitions: `sudo parted -l` and `df -h` in above qestion, so you can format them.

Comment: Show me a screenshot of `gparted`, and then I can make a recommendation.

Comment: @heynnema https://ibb.co/Z8vt5MR and https://ibb.co/61Yx8z1

Comment: It doesn't look like you dual-boot with Windows, so why the two NTFS partitions? What's on /dev/sdb2? Can any of it be deleted or moved?

Comment: @heynnema yes i'm doing dual booting with Windows, this time i partitioned a bigger part for Linux

Comment: Is /dev/sdb2 your Windows C: partition? What data is there that takes so much room? Do you share this data with Ubuntu?

Comment: 25 GB is plenty for a linux root partition with a separate home. I would first inspect what is occupying all that space. There must be data there that do not belong there and that can be moved elsewhere. Inspect this from a live session. It could be that your /home folder on sdb3 still contains data, which you will not see in normal operation when sdb4 is mounted there. There could be gigantic log files, or other data...

Comment: You refer to "Downloading". You should not be downloading in your root partition. Your user's Downloads folder is on sda4, under your /home. There is plenty of space there. Please explain more precise what you mean by "downloading".